# Return winner of football match from a melted data set

Tags: r, data.table

I have, for example, a 'melted' dataset of football results as below:

```
library(data.table)
match.data <- "
game,team,score
1,newcastle,3
1,aston villa,2
2,chelsea,1
2,fulham,1
3,leicester,28
3,man city,0
"
DT <- data.table(read.csv(textConnection(match.data)))
```

Each row gives the number of goals scored by one of the teams in the match. I would like to produce a dataset of who won the match (NA if it was a draw). For my example this would produce:

```
   game    winner
1:    1 newcastle
2:    2        NA
3:    3 leicester
```

Secondly, how do I describe what I'm trying to do in English!?! I'm grouping by game, and returning the name of the team that corresponds to a max function of their scores. I don't know how to describe this operation properly so had to use an example!

Whilst I would like a solution using `data.table`, `dplyr` (or even base R!) would also be acceptable. I use `data.table` for illustration.

Comment: You're really just aggregating

Comment: Thanks, still finding terminology a little tricky.

Comment: @Downvoter - please could you provide some feedback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works if `team` is stored as `character`:

```
DT[ , if (diff(score) == 0) NA_character_ else team[which.max(score)], by = game]
```

Change to `NA_integer_` if `team` is stored as a `factor`.